# What's the best way to make a table in Vue?

Tags: datatable, bootstrap-4, vue-component, nuxt.js, tabulator

I need to make tables in my project. Early, I used to deal with the Tabulator. But it was in the Thymleaf.

Now, I do a project on Nuxt.js.

I tried a few things in the tabulator and I didn't like the following:
1. I couldn't set the 'method' on the 'cellClick' event in the column.
2. I couldn't use this.$axios in function callbacks. $axios undefined in functions callbacks.
3. How much do I understand the Tabulator uses jQuery? I think it isn't good.
In general, it seemed to me that the tabulator is not quite intended for use in Vue.

**If I'm wrong, correct me.**

I try to use Bootstrap-Vue's table component, nut I can't find how to do an editable table, to do copy/paste clipboard, how to do grouping row.

**In general, I'm asking you to help me with the selection of the tool to build the tables.**

I need a few major opportunities:

1. Copy/paste/load tables from Excel or clipboard, because I will need inputting a big table and input each cell difficult task.
2. A grouping row.
3. An editable tables

Answer (score 1):

Tabulator dosnt use any jQuery it is pure JavaScript with zero dependencies.

It also has full [Vue Support](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/frameworks#vue) and a fully functioning [Vue Component](https://vue-tabulator.netlify.com/)

It has [Clipboard Support](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/clipboard)

and [Row Grouping](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/group)

and a full suite of built in [Data Editors](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/edit)

Comment: Do you know if there are plans for further development of the Vue-Tabulator? As far as I understand, not all the functions are implemented in it. For example, not all callbacks work.

Comment: The Vue Component is actively maintained, if there is a feature missing please create an issue on their GItHub page. The component is only a shim around the core Tabulator library, the framework support page in the Tabulator docs explains how to use Tabulator in view without the component